# Xcode Git Fresh Start

Tags: xcode, git, github, bitbucket

I have recently rewritten a great deal of my project for optimization and I'm happy to report it went beautifully and even though it saves milliseconds at most, it's so worth it! As to my real issue, I hate anything git-related.

Before I changed my code, I made sure to backup my code by committing and I thought everything was good. I just went back to recommit after making my edits and the commit button is greyed out. I don't know what the issue is but after several hours of researching how to make a remote repository and all that time-saving, headache-reducing housekeeping, I have come to the conclusion that I don't want any part of it, my project is littered with "commits" and I have different repositories hooked up to the same project and I'm terrified to change anything or clean it up as it could delete my code.

Finally, my question is, how can I remove any ounce of git-related stuff from my project without ruining my project or losing any code. I truly believe git has one of the worst learning curves in all of development especially when the alternative is just making a copy of your project folder. If someone could save me from added headache, I would be so thankful. The solution could turn out to be giving in to the all-mighty git and being pointed to that oh so helpful resource to sum it all up.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I remove any ounce of git-related stuff from my project without ruining my project or losing any code

First, make sure the code is the way you want it.

Then, at the command line, `cd` into your project folder and say

```
rm -rf .git
```

Your code is completely unaffected. It looks exactly the same as it did before you said that. And, all trace of Git is gone.